# Can a module have its own config file?

Tags: yii

I just want to know if we can add a config file that extends the main.conf in the module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does, already.  in the CWebModule through $this->setComponents as follows:

```
<?php

    class AccountModule extends CWebModule
    {
        public function init()
        {
            // this method is called when the module is being created
            // you may place code here to customize the module or the application

            $this->setComponents(array(
                'errorHandler' => array(
                        'errorAction' => 'module/default/error'),
                'defaultController' => 'default',
                'user' => array(
                        'class' => 'ModuleWebUser',
                        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                        'loginUrl' => Yii::app()->createUrl('module/default/login'),
                )
            ));

            // import the module-level models and components or any other components..
            $this->setImport(array(
                'module.models.*',
                'module.components.*',
            ));
        }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to make an array item for your module/etc in the params item of the main config array.

Look at this forum post: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24617-custom-configuration/

if you want your configuration to be in a separate file you can merge it with the main config array in the config file!
something like this should work:

```
include("custom_config.php"); // define $array_from_custom_conf inside this file
return array_merge(
   array(/*main_config_array from main.php*/),
   $array_from_custom_conf
);
```

If you put your custom config array as the 2nd argument it will also overwrite attributes from the main config.

Answer (score 1):

I've never did it but:

- A current solution is provided in [a wiki article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/52/encapsulate-db-and-module-configurations/).
- Regarding this 'feature request', its not a big surprise that this was already requested on Yii's forums. See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21854-modules/) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/34026-configurationdi-container/).